# ANDROID: make listview elements cliccable if it have an url

Tags: android, url, listview

i have this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Bookmarks extends ListActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bookmarks);
    Database info=new Database(this);
    info.open();
    String data=info.getData();
    String[] data_array = data.split(",");
    info.close();
    ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_mia);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data_array);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id){
            if(data_array[position].startsWith("http://")){
                //do this
            }else{
                //do this
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

which is working properly.
how can i make the item cliccable if it have an url?
i've tried various help aroud the web, buit i can't make it work!
thanks

Comment: i don't understand your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
  if(data_array[position].startsWith("http://")){
//do this
}
else{
//do this
}
 }
});
```

Comment: it says i need an argument on setOnItemClickListener

Comment: you already have a data array and position of item which  is clicked.

Comment: The method setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the arguments ()

yes i'm setting this in onCreate because it's different from the other setOnClick

Comment: nope. same error :-(

i must put it after my listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
correct?

Comment: yes. ensure that you are using  "android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()" this one

Comment: nope:

it gives 1 error on OnItemClickListener():
The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long))

and one on View view:
View cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: if you are using eclipse press ctrl+shift+o to orginize youe imports. and add this @Override before onitemClick.